# Highcharts hidden flag

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to force chart to show left flag?

http://jsfiddle.net/25hBZ/

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart',{

  series: [
      {data: [[1397760750356,1],[1401353540540,10],[1401455794172,100]], type: 'spline'},

      {"name":"ELOXATIN","data":[[1397760750356,15],[1401455794172,15]],"type":"spline","id":"dataseries_17328","enableMouseTracking":false},

      {"type":"flags","data":[{"x":1397760750356,"title":"A","text":"something"},{"x":1401455794172,"title":"B","text":"something"}],"onSeries":"dataseries_17328","shape":"squarepin"}
  ]
});
```

http://monosnap.com/image/3vs327Xw0A62ktOAENBJDc2O7jmCqr

I've tried with setting extremes, maxPadding, minPadding and nothing. The problem is only for flags on edges.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's a bug, I have reported it here: [3119](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3119) - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I can see is add an additional "null" in the "data" attribute.

```
  {data: [[null,null],[1397760750356,1],[1401353540540,10],[1401455794172,100]], type: 'spline'},
```

Once you click on YTD or 1y, the items show up just fine except the navigation at the bottom can scroll left.

Added the following based on your comment:

```
xAxis: {
    min: 1390000000000  
},
```

That will ensure that you are properly zoomed in from the correct position. Though keep in mind, if your data is dynamic, you would need to round it somehow so it would be displayed.

Comment: It is some solution but now I have to much space on left http://monosnap.com/image/oAqkQPh2DZh7w2vkt5tEHsqplNAwDl. I just need about 30px...

Comment: That's correct, I mentioned that if you click on YTD or 1y, it zooms in appropriately. However, I've edited the above response which will hopefully help you out further.